# How to put three different disks with three different OSs together - Ubuntu Boot-Repair not working

Tags: linux, boot, windows, dual-boot

## The Problem (short version):

I have a Dell XPS 8700 that came with Windows 8.1 (**sda**). After a while trying I've managed to install an ***old*** 2nd HD to have Linux (Fedora, then Ubuntu) installed (**sdb**). It was working (Ubuntu), but sdb is too old (and presenting bad blocks) and then I decided to buy a third one (**sdc**): a Kingston SSD SA400S37 to properly have Linux (Ubuntu) installed.

I could install the Linux into it without errors but can have **grub** working at all.

Several errors occurred and, after some test (see below please), I could put my old Linux (sdb) to work again. My new Linux appears at grub menu, but I can't boot: it says that "Can't read kernel /vmlinux-5.4.0-42-generic ..."

> Important detail:
> The computer is in Raid mode because of the mSATA drive that works with Intel Rapid Storage on Windows.

## What I want:

**What I really want:** to make the new Linux the default one and have it controlling the grub properly, even if this means that I have to reinstall it again (for the 5th time). I really want Fedora, not Ubuntu in the **sdc**, but I'll be glad to have my Linux back.

## What I'll be glad if I can have:

**I'd like at least to:** correct the grub from my old Linux (in sdb) that is working to boot it, but also to allow me to boot the new Linux (in sdc). I've made searches on how to edit the grub config file, but I couldn't solve my problem, using the **blkid** and **lsblk** and lost the time I don't have. I need to keep the new Ubuntu since soon I'll have to retire the old HD.

#### What I tried (short version):

1. Installing the new Ubuntu 20.04 into **sdc** without formatting **sda1** (EFI partition for Windows and Old Linux) and without errors, but without succeeding to boot from it.
2. Used a Live-USB disk with Ubuntu 20.04 to install and use Boot-Repair without the "Recommended Repair". I decided that because it would:

   - use sdb as default and I wanted sdc;
   - repair Windows boot files (I really didn't know - and still don't - if it would mess with my windows install)
   - use SecureBoot: my BIOS was set to not use Secure Boot. So I've changed it.
3. I decided to try Boot-Repair again since the last step resulted in a blank (black screen) in the first boot and a malfunctioning one after I managed to boot into Windows (Boot menu - F12). Malfunctioning = Grub without any other OS booting, but Windows.
4. And tried again, and again, and again... with different results each step: but all of them with errors varying from the blank (black screen) to the ones [in this figure](https://photos.app.goo.gl/mvdHTuzNvWiUzg4p8) and [this one too](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Dr64RcP4yJbRCsVe9).
5. In one of my last tries I found [this error](https://photos.app.goo.gl/hC7zToGE7SWisuU9A) running Boot-Repair commands.
6. In the last try, I put **sdb** as the default one and now I'm using the old Linux again, without access to my new one via the now functioning grub. Can boot into Windows.
7. I ran fsck from the old Ubuntu to check sdc and:

   - Checking separately: sdc1 and sdc2 it give no errors, saying the system is clean, giving me the number of files and blocks
   - Checking it as a whole: fsck /dev/sdc, give errors saying that:

     - ext2fs_open2: bad magic number in super-block
     - fsck.ext2: superblock invalid, ...
     - fsck.ext2: bad magic number in super-block trying to open /dev/sdc
     - The super-block couldn't be read or doesn't describe a valid system ext2/ext3/ext4. If the device is valid and really contains a system ext2/ext3/ext4 ... so the super-block is corrupted and can try to execute e2fsck with an alternative super-block: e2fsck -b 8193 or e2fsck -b 32768
     - Found gpt partition table in /dev/sdc
8. Tried to edit the grub config file of the old Ubuntu to allow me to boot the new one from sdc without success. I only lost the time that I don't have.
9. I can't list here the exact sources (too many during a long period of time) I used to do everything I did until today.

> ---
>
> Really want to hear from you as soon as possible. Thank you in advance for any help.
> I do appreciate any help or ideas. Best regards,
> Patrick.
>
> ---

## Appendix

#### What I know and don't know:

1. There's still garbage from Fedora files inside the EFI partition.
2. Don't know if one Ubuntu 20.04 is messing with the other one inside EFI partition
3. Don't know if I can set the EFI partition for formatting when installing Fedora, for instance. Will it erase my Windows files.
4. After all these years using Linux and deprecating Windows, it is the only one that works perfectly on my computer.
5. I don't know what the **fsck error** represents and will seek for this also, but I don't know if this has something to do with the errors I've been facing with boot and/or Boot Repair or Linux installations.

#### What really happened (The very long version):

It is inside this file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OoYsD-kA8gRo8ECYAxWYZ-tIQ3SaD91S/view?usp=sharing

The Stackoverflow editor said that my formatted text was like spam, despite the fact that I don't know exactly what I'm spreading or selling. So I had to put it into another platform.

**Really want to hear from you as soon as possible. Thank you in advance for any help.
Best regards,
Patrick.**

Comment: I prefer to see link to Summary Report from Boot Repair. Are all installs UEFI? Are all drives gpt? Report will show that. But have you changed drives to AHCI in UEFI? Updated UEFI and SSD firmware even if new system?  This is a question & answer site that prefers one question, so we can give one answer and others can easy find & use that. Your request works better in a forum like: https://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php

Comment: Yes. All installs are UEFI and all drives are gpt. No, I haven't changed to AHCI or wouldn't be able to boot to any OS. Perhaps you can give me a tip to how to boot from the sdc. Or how to reinstall Ubuntu in the sdc and make the grub work. I tried different approaches (LVM, ordinary partition, /boot locations) without success. The only thing unchanged in all attempts is that /boot/efi pointed to sda1 (Windows EFI partition). I couldn't post all links but I think I can post a link to a file with all of them. I'll try the forum. Thank you very much for your attention. Best regards, Patrick.

Comment: If you just want UEFI boot entry for sdc install and have an ESP on sdc, you can reinstall grub to it. It is Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer that only installs to first drive. We filed bug years ago and still no change. Now several work arounds. Disconnect physically or logically in UEFI, all other drives, remove boot flag from all other ESP, reinstall grub manually or with Boot-Repair or this: Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Thank you for your support. As I'm in the final steps of an important project I can't try anything demanding to much time now. I'll try what you pointed to me, but I tried something simpler: unplugged the sdb (old) HD and reinstalled Ubuntu into the sdc again, after cleaning EFI (sda1) partition from any Linux files. No errors during installation, but got a weird (graphically) grub I received the message:"error: failure reading sector 0x5468a40..." I ran fsck from LiveUSB and got no errors. It's the same process I took to have Ubuntu in sdb. Could it be a problem with my SSD?

Comment: What video card/chip? Grub tries to use video mode of install, but sometimes you have to manually set a default. But if one sector not normally an issue, but if multiple sectors it can be a problem.

Comment: It's AMD Radeon R7 370, which I think it was one of my problems with Fedora. What I don't get it's why I could do the Ubuntu install with the 2nd HD and worked perfectly with the default install settings (grub in sda) and now I can't get it working doing the same thing, but for a different HD type: a SSD. I'm almost giving it up. Really tired and without time for pushing so hard to have something working the way it should. When I started with Linux I used to have the time to learn things this way. It would b better if I didn't have to work with Windows apps.I do appreciate your help.Thank you.

Comment: I have had no issues with SSD, but have had to update SSD firmware. Samsung had an ISO just for my model as I do not have Windows, so could not use its Windows app for firmware updates.

Comment: I didn't try the update, but thanks for your concern. In the end, I think is the case for rebuilding the whole thing: use the SSD for both 1 Windows and 1 Linux. As long as had tons of work to do I bought a new computer, and now it's running both (W10 and Ubuntu) smoothly. I'll take some time at the end of this year to rebuild the old system, so I can have a backup machine. Thanks, @oldfred for all your help, I appreciate that.